# When plugging a second monitor via HDMI, videos have no sound

Tags: sound, 22.04, hdmi

Ubuntu 22.04.2 laptop

Steps to reproduce:

1. Connect monitor via HDMI
2. Make sure audio is set to laptop and not to monitor

There will be system sounds but no sounds from browser videos (Firefox).

I have tried `pulseaudio -k`

What steps can I take to troubleshoot?

Comment: Check if switching to the apt version of Firefox helps https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466